# Change "Referer" in QtWebEngineView

Tags: http-headers, qtwebengine

I need to dynamically change "Referer" in HTTP header with `QtWebEngineView`. I can change other fields like "Accept" via inheritance of `QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor` and overriding of `interceptRequest` method, but for some reason "Referer" do not changed. So, why "Referer" do not changed after calling `QWebEngineUrlRequestInfo`'s method `setHttpHeader` and how I can change that header? Thanks.